# Custom Domain not loading CSS (Azure)

Tags: css, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

The custom domain I've been using (which is already linked to an App Service in Microsoft Azure Portal) is not loading the my current styles files (.css files). Actually, it's loading older versions of those files, which I didn't create (they've had been created previously by another employee).

Has someone experienced this same issue? If I go to the website created by the App Service, the .CSS loaded there is correct (the one I've created), but whenever I go to the custom domain linked with this website, the .CSS loaded is older.

Comment: Just Check the path of CSS files . If you custom domain is inside another folder than you have to correct the path.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the browser cache will work locally. However, other repeat visitors will have the same issue you are having. A global method would be to rename your CSS file. That will force the browser for repeat visitor's to load the new/ current CSS file.

ex. "style.css" --> "styles.css"

Rename the CSS file and don't forget to rename the meta link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing browser cache memory. CSS files are often get cached in the browsers.